# User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I am attempting to follow the "API Gateway resource policy only" flow on this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-authorization-flow.html#apigateway-authorization-flow-resource-policy-only

When attempting to access a protected route using the authorization signature, I am getting a response that reads as if API Gateway believes the request is being made by an anonymous user instead of a credentialed user.

I have a public API Gateway deployment with the below resource policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*/api/GET/server"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/api-auth"
      },
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*/api/POST/server"
    }
  ]
}
```

**What is not expected** is that when I attempt to access the `POST` route using the `aws4_request` Auth signature using `api-auth` user's access/secret key, I get:

> User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> import requests
>>> from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
>>> 
>>> auth = AWS4Auth("<access-key>", "<secret-key>", "us-east-1", "execute-api")
>>> response = requests.request("POST", "https://<endpoint>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/server", auth=auth, data='', headers={})
>>> print(response.text)
{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:<account-id>:<endpoint>/api/POST/server"}
```

The user has the below policy

```
{
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
   "Resource": "*"
}
```

From what I can tell on the troubleshooting doc, I should be configured correctly: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/

**Edit 1**

My example uses `requests_aws4auth`, which should be creating correct headers. As another example, the below generated from Postman results in the same problem:

```
curl --location --request POST '<endpoint>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/server' \
--header 'X-Amz-Content-Sha256: <data>' \
--header 'X-Amz-Date: <date-data>' \
--header 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<access-key>/<date>/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=<signature>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '<request>"}'
```

---

*For what it is worth...*

1. Accessing the `GET` route without `Authorization` works fine. This is expected.
2. When trying to access the `POST` route without an `Authorization` signature in the header, I receive the same `User: anonymous` message. This is also expected.

Comment: `User: anonymous` tells you that your authentication attempt in the `auth` object isn't being recognised. Your request seems to be signed differently to [this example in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html) e.g. you have no `x-amz-date` header, and the docs say

> "Host" and "x-amz-date" are always required.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @rowanu - the python package I'm using in my example (`requests-aws4auth`) inserts those headers for me. As another example, I have included a `curl` request that produces the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

For the resource policy to allow access to a particular method, you need to set the "Authorization" settings under "Method execution" to "AWS_IAM"